# RTL animation Expression

Tags: after-effects

I have an issue with animate my text with an expression but right to left,here is the code:
Expression Selector Based On : Characters

```
delay = .1;  
myDelay = delay*textIndex;  
t = (time - inPoint) - myDelay;  
if (t >= 0){  
  freq =2;  
  amplitude = 07;  
  decay = 8.0;  
  s = amplitude*Math.cos(freq*t*2*Math.PI)/Math.exp(decay*t);  
  [s,s]  
}else{  
  value  
}
```

The problem is my text animates from left to right, I want it to be from right to left.How can I ?

Answer (score 1):

Try replace myDelay by:

```
myDelay = delay*(thisLayer.text.sourceText.length+1-textIndex);
```